# Kernel panic and keyboard led flashing

Tags: linux, kernel-panic

My server recently just froze. I was unable to ping it, It did not respond to any keystrokes at all and the caps lock and scroll lock was flashing in unison with a steady off-on-off-on rate approx. once a second or so.
Edit: My monitor was blank as well (that *may* be the monitor itself just for the record).

I am running Debian Squeeze with kernel 2.6.32-5-amd64 and the only software that I immediately suspect to be the cause of the panic could be VirtualBox 3.2.10 who I am using that runs a few VM's.

Anyway, I have been trying to find some information on the flashing keyboard led's to figure out if they can tell me anything about the reason for the panic but there is a lot of information from the kernel sending morse code to the kernel just indicating a crash.

What does the flashing leds mean (if anything) and how can I get more information about what caused the crash (if anything had time to end up on a physical disk that is).

Comment: Is this a "headless" server? If it is, maybe you should attach a monitor for debugging, and post a picture of the panic.

Comment: This is indeed a headless server, however I keep a monitor nearby so I can connect for situations like this. For this example the monitor was without signal. E.g. not only a black screen but in fact not even a signal.

Comment: Is BIOS okay? This may be a BIOS problem, even before you get to the kernel.

Comment: My server froze hence it is not frozen :) e.g. everything is up and running fine. I am asking the questions to learn if the flashing leds' on a kernel panic means anything at all.

Comment: Oh... You should have said it thawed... ;)